# properly editing a shell buffer with evil-mode

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

I'm using evil-mode. When I type `M-x multi-term` zsh opens up.

I then type `bcdef` in the terminal. Then I hit `ESC` to enter normal mode, then `b` so my cursor is place on `b` of the `bcdef` word. Then I hit `i` to enter insert mode and then I type `a` to insert an `a`.

Instead of inserting the `a` where I wanted, emacs inserts the `a` in the end of the word.

What is happening? how do I achieve the desired normal behaviour?

this only happens in shell buffers.

Comment: Is the name of the buffer `*shell*`, `*terminal*`, or `*ansi-term*`, or something else? I'm not familiar with `multi-term`, so I'm not sure which Emacs shell/terminal emulator you're in.

Comment: did you find the answer?

Comment: yes. you actually have to type ESC through another key combo. like, pick C-C C-E. that should produce an ESC that is not eaten by emacs and goes directly to zsh. take a look at my config files github.com/ninrod/dotfiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to produce an `ESC` that is eaten by the terminal but not by emacs/evil. If you just press `ESC`, then emacs/evil will eat the `ESC` and not send the `ESC` to the terminal.

You can produce an `ESC` that is eaten by the terminal, but not emacs, by hitting `C-C C-E` in emacs-mode. Here is what `C-h k` tells me:

```
C-c C-e runs the command term-send-esc (found in term-raw-map), which
is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
‘~/code/sources/dotfiles/emacs/elpa/multi-term-20160619.233/multi-term.el’.

It is bound to C-c <escape>, C-c C-e, <emacs-state> C-c <escape>.

(term-send-esc)

Send ESC in term mode.
```